# Repeating a max.col across multiple files using R

Tags: r, excel

I have a number of excel files (.xlsx) that store athlete VO2max testing data that I want to analyse as a group. Each file represents 1 client and I can get all the files into a list in R with the following code:

`files <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/.../vo2 tests", pattern = "*.xlsx", full.names = T)`

I then want to be able to find the maximum value from a specific column of a specific sheet in the excel files (this is the clients VO2max). So far the following code works to find the value I need but only returns a result for 1 of the files, however I want the function to run and collect from each of the excel files and output into a new data frame:

`tbl <- lapply(files, read_excel, sheet = "Averages", skip = 2)`

`max(tbl[[1]][["ml/Kg/min"]])`

Once I have all of the VO2max values into a new data frame I want to take the average & standard deviation of this new data set for reporting. The aim being I can provide my clients with a constantly updating ranking system of their performance compared to other athletes. Any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: [Opening all files in a folder, and applying a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564489/opening-all-files-in-a-folder-and-applying-a-function); `lapply(<list-of-data frames>, <function-to-apply-to-each-data frame>)`

Comment: [Read all files in directory and apply multiple functions to each data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958516/read-all-files-in-directory-and-apply-multiple-functions-to-each-data-frame)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the file, you can take `max` of the column in each file.

```
all_maxs <- sapply(tbl, function(x) max(x[["ml/Kg/min"]], na.rm = TRUE))
```

You can then take `mean` or `sd` of `all_maxs`.

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thank you!!