# use apply file list for a function in R

Tags: r, function, lapply

I've created this function to get some information from two different files

```
   create_distance_to_strand <- function(data, data2, nameCsv) {
      newData  <- data  %>% 
        select(seqnames, start, end, V4, seqnames, geneStart, geneEnd, geneStrand, distanceToTSS, SYMBOL, geneLength)%>%
        rename(peak = V4)
      
      joined_df <- merge(newData , closest_dist, by.x = "peak", 
                         by.y = "peak", all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE) %>% drop_na()
      
      write.table(joined_df , nameCsv, sep = "\t")
    
      
      return(joined_df)
    }
    
    closest_dist = read.csv("closest_distance", header = T, sep ="\t")
    annotation = read.csv("results_annotation", header = T, sep ="\t") 
    myDistanceToStrand <- create_distance_to_strand(annotation,  closest_dist, "frame.csv")
```

It works as expected. However, I'm trying to make it more efficient in case I'd have different `"closest_dist"` files, in order to apply the function to all the files.
I've tried this:

```
    files <- list.files(pattern = "closest*")
    proof = lapply(files, create_distance_to_strand(annotation,  closest_dist, "proof.csv"))
```

But does not work

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
      error in evaluating the argument 'y' in selecting a method for function 'merge': object 'closest_dist' not found
```

Any advice?
Thank you

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14958516/680068

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have different `closest_dist` files which are saved in `files`, you can use `lapply` to pass them one by one. We can use an anonymous function here -

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "closest*")
proof = lapply(files, function(x) create_distance_to_strand(annotation,  x, "proof.csv"))
```

To have a separate output file you may pass different `nameCsv` value as well.

```
Map(function(x, y) create_distance_to_strand(annotation, x, y), 
    files, sprintf('proof%d.csv', seq_along(files)))
```

Comment: my bad to forgot the anonymous function. However, it only generate one csv, and not one per file. Any idea about how to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: @lana because you are overwriting the same file - proof.csv. Use paste0, to create files like proof1.csv proof2.csv, etc

Comment: Yes, that is because we are passing the same filename "proof.csv" in every iteration. You may create a vector of filenames and pass it separately using `Map`. See the updated answer.